# ROR Hosting having functionality like heroku and MySQL DBMS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, hosting, heroku

I've bought a script which uses rails 2.3.5 and MySQL.

I deployed it on my computer and it was working fine but when I uploaded that script on heroku, some functionality does not work. When I checked the heroku logs, I realized that most of the errors were related to PostgreSQL.

I tried other hosting services but most of them don't let us install gems or they have a peculiar process for installing gems where we have to contact their admins for required gems.

Is there any other hosting service which has MySQL DBMS and which will allow us to install gems directly on their server?

Comment: It won't be too difficult to migrate to postgre; which errors are reported? Are you averse to updating the application?

Comment: I'm also considering the updation but if I can find a proper host then there's no point in spending time and money on updating the app.

Comment: Oh well if it's a case of spending money then you're right though I would definitely call heroku a proper host. Are you averse to any technical work because of you look through the errors you'll probably be able to fix them by asking here. Dreamhost are apparently good on the other hand.

Comment: Dreamhost isn't that good. I think I should consider updating my app.

Comment: I think so too. Have a look through your error logs and you'll probably find you have repetition of a small number of errors which you could ask here in a new question.

Comment: Re: Cloud Foundry.You should be able to test it for free. Signing up gives you: 2G of available memory, 16 available services, and 20 available apps. http://support.cloudfoundry.com/entries/20012337-getting-started-guide-command-line-vmc-users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought about using Heroku with a mysql Amazon RDS instance? Costs might be a bit non-trivial, starting at around $0.11 per hour, but it should do what you need. If budgets are tight, you could look at running mysql on a micro instance yourself (more complex to set up, but cheaper to run).

Either way, you can configure your Heroku application to connect to the mysql instance and pull data from there instead of your Heroku database. Should perform pretty well, as Heroku (currently at least) runs inside Amazon EC2.

Comment: Budget is not an issue here. Our app is not compatible with the Postgre that's why I was searching for a host having MySQL as their DBMS

Comment: So as I say, you can hook Heroku up to Amazon's mysql RDS quite easily. There's a Heroku add-on for it, so it's mostly point and click.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had the chance to use it yet, but look into [Cloud Foundry](http://www.cloudfoundry.com/faq). It's fairly new and not as polished as Heroku, but their services include MySQL, Redis, and MongoDB data services.

Comment: It looks good but it is in the beta stage and it does not have a starter plan which will allow me to test it.

Answer (score 0):

you could try and get an invite for dotcloud, but it's still beta - it let's you choose from many different components to build you application on - mysql is one of them :)

Comment: I've already signed up for it few days ago but they didn't send me the account details. But still I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw an ad of Engine Yard on this very page. It looks promising. It has a graphical interface for installing gems and it lets us choose between MySQL and PostgrSQL.

[Engine Yard](http://www.engineyard.com/)